# Rotated PDF Doesn't Save State?

Tags: pdf, preview

For some strange reason, when I rotate a PDF using the trackpad (Two finger multi-touch rotation gesture.), there's no option to save it and all changes are lost after I close it.

(The save button is grayed out.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

... Never mind. Apparently rotating using the trackpad of a PDF in Preview is just for cosmetic purposes. You have to rotate using +L or +R or within the Apple-bar menu. Only after that, the save option will be available. :|

Strange.

Comment: that is certainly strange... glad you figured it out and posted the answer so others won't have to get frustrated if they encounter this issue :P

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, using <kbd></kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd></kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> seems to modify the PDF in place.

But if you use the rotation gesture on the trackpad, and use `Save As`, it will save the PDF with the pages rotated.